# How to return promise with modifications from async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an async function and I need to do the following in this function:

- If ajaxRequest succeeds then I must process value and return it in Promise,
- Otherwise return Promise with null.

This is what I did:

```
 public async foo(): Promise<B> {
    const promiseA: Promise<A> = ajaxRequest(...);
    promiseA.then((a) => {
      return new Promise<B>((resolve) => {
         const b: B = process(a); 
         resolve(b);
      })
    });
    promise.catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
      return new Promise<B>((resolve) => {
         resolve(null);
      })
    })
  }
```

And I get `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` compilation error. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Generally: don't mix and match `async` with `.then`...

Comment: Why do you have an async function that doesn't use await? Why do you create a new Promise in what's already a promise chain? And why don't you return that promise chain?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am a very beginner in promises, async etc. Could you show how to do it?

Comment: Then run through a tutorial, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function seems to simplify to

```
class Something {
  public async foo(): Promise<B | null> {
    try {
      const a = await ajaxRequest(...);
      return process(a);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

assuming `process` returns `B`.